# how to convert date time in variable to ISO 8601 format?

Tags: python

I'm working on my python sitemap generator and the problem is with `<lastmod>` tag style.

I have below date time style automatically generated by MYSQL timestamp():
2024-01-26 00:39:24

And I want to know how to change top style date time to below style for sitemap `<lastmod>` tag using python3 ?

2024-01-03T12:52:51+00:00

Below code is working but use current date time not my style (2024-01-26 00:39:24) fetched from db.

I don't know how to convert my style to apply below functions (to get something like 2020-03-20T14:31:43+13:00).

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.now().astimezone().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
2020-03-20T14:31:43+13:00
```

Comment: Why the "python-2.7" tag? Also, it's far from clear what you did, what happens and what you expect instead. Please start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: The format must be ISO 8601 According to the sitemap.xml protocol specification (https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html)

Comment: Wait, what's the problem? You already have the answer, no? `.isoformat()`. If the input data is actually a string, see [Convert string "Jun 1 2005 1:33PM" into datetime](/q/466345/4518341). Otherwise, make a [mre]. I'm confused because the format you're showing is the exact same as `print(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0))`.

Comment: The question I linked is too generic. Instead see [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date and time?](/q/127803/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import dateutil.parser as parser

text = '2024-01-26 00:39:24'
date = parser.parse(text).astimezone().replace(microsecond=0)
print(date.isoformat())
```

2024-01-26T00:39:24+03:30

Comment: You don't need another package for this. You can use `datetime.datetime.fromisoformat()`,